# Plot connections between countries

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data about trades between countries and I want to plot it in a worldmap, with one line per trade so that it shows the amount of commerce between each pair of countries.  Another option would be to use only one line between each pair of countries with its width adjusted to the number of trades between the countries.

My goal would be something like this:
[image: map1]

[This repository](https://github.com/rafapereirabr/flow-map-in-r-ggplot) (the one the image comes from) contains some information about how to do something like this for flight data, but I haven't been able to do it with mine.

My data looks like this:

```
trade_data <- data.frame(origin = c("United States", "United States",
                                    "United States", "China", "China",
                                    "United Kingdom"),
                         dest = c("United States", "United States", "France",
                                  "China","United States", "Germany"))
```

I've tried:

```
library(rworldmap)
worldmap <- getMap()

# Add latitude and longitude to each country 
trade_data <- trade_data %>%
  left_join(select(as.data.frame(worldmap), NAME, LON, LAT),
             by = c("origin" = "NAME")) %>%
  left_join(select(as.data.frame(worldmap), NAME, LON, LAT),
             by = c("dest" = "NAME"))

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = worldmap, aes(long,lat, group=group), fill="gray") +
  geom_curve(data = trade_data, aes(x = LON.x, y = LAT.x, xend = LON.y, yend = LAT.y),
             curvature = -0.2)
```

And I get an: `Error in calcCurveGrob(x, x$debug) : end points must not be identical`.

I've tried modifying the toy data frame to remove the data with the same origin and destination:

```
trade_data <- data.frame(origin = c("United States", "United States",
                                    "United Kingdom", "Vietnam", "China",
                                    "United Kingdom"),
                         dest = c("United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "France",
                                  "China","United States", "Germany"))
```

Then, the code above works:
[image]

However, there is only one line between each two countries (not showing the amount of trade happening between them), and I'd also want to show trades that happen in the same country with a line to itself: US -> US.

Comment: `geom_curve` should take the color aesthetic. Add the frequency/ size/ whatever dimension you have of trade into your `trade_data` data frame as a new column and add this as color aesthetic to `geom_curve`. How is a line from a country to itself supposed to look like? I personally think this would overcrowd the graph - maybe plot a separate map with this data, e.g. simply as dots , also colored by trade quantitiy

Comment: another approach might be to use `geom_path` instead of `geom_curve` the [details](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html) page says "See `geom_path` if you need to connect points across multiple cases.". There is a great example here: http://strimas.com/spatial/long-flights/ As @Tjebo asked, I'm not sure how a line from a country to itself is meant to look but I suggest you either jitter the locations or find the individuals cities/places within the country itself